# ajax returns error but the process was successful

Tags: ajax

My ajax always returns error each time I run it but when I refresh the page the data was updated upon each trigger

My ajax

```
    $.ajax({
    url:"exe/deduct.php",`enter code here`
    method:"POST",
    data: {deductQty: deductQty, itemID: itemID, oldQty: oldQty},
    success: function(data){
         alert(data);
         window.location.href="deduct.php";
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception){
         alert(data);
    }
});
```

My PHP Code

```
    <?php
    include('database.php');
    if($_POST){
      $itemID = $_POST['itemID'];
      $deductQty = $_POST['deductQty'];
      $oldQty = $_POST['oldQty'];

      $answer = $oldQty - $deductQty;

      $query = "UPDATE `item` SET `qty` = '$answer' WHERE `id` = '$itemID'";
      if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
          echo "Restock Success";
      }else{
          echo "Restock Failed";
      }
    }

?>
```

Comment: remove `enter code here`

Comment: There is no parameter with the name `data` in your error function? What are you alerting?

Answer (score 0):

make sure the `url` location is accurate.

the `response` can be print inside a div `$('#divid').html(response);`

```
$.ajax({
url:"exe/deduct.php",
method:"POST",
data: {deductQty: deductQty, itemID: itemID, oldQty: oldQty},
success: function(response){
     alert(response);
     //$('#divid').html(response);
     //window.location.href="deduct.php";
},
error: function(jqXHR, exception){
    var message = '';

    if (jqXHR.status === 0)
    message = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
    else if (jqXHR.status == 404)
    message = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
    else if (jqXHR.status == 500)
    message = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
    else if (exception === 'parsererror')
    message = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
    else if (exception === 'timeout')
    message = 'Time out error.';
    else if (exception === 'abort')
    message = 'Ajax request aborted.';
    else
    message = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;

    alert(message);
}
});
```

Comment: it keeps saying  Not connect Verify Network but when I refresh the page the data was already deducted

Comment: How did you trigger the event to run the above codes? Is that run on when click on some buttons?

Comment: I used this code:
$("#restockBtn").on("click",function(){
//ajax here
});